# Picasso Library image loading not working with Firebase auth.getCurentUser.getPhotoUrl

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, picasso

I'm currently working on a chat apps using Firebase. For Firebase auth, I'm using `getImageUrl()` to get image Uri from Firebase User, 
but Picasso Library does not load any image to show also not getting any error, but when I use Direct link, it works perfectly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseUser User;
    private ImageView profileImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        User = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        profileImg= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profilenameTv);
                    name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                    profileImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(profileImg);
                }else{
                    // User is signed out
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Signup.class));
                }
            }
        };


    }
```

Here is my EditProfile class:

```
public class editProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private FirebaseUser User;

    private Button submitBtn, changePassBtn, deleteBtn;
    private ImageButton addProImage;
    private EditText UsernameEt, currentPassEt, newPassEt ;

    int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private Uri PhotoDownloadUri ;
    private Uri photoUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        //firebase initilation
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mDatabase.getReference();
        User = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //View initialization
        //EditText
        UsernameEt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEt);
        currentPassEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.curentPass);
        newPassEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPass);
        //Button
        submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sumitBtn);
        changePassBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangePassBtn);
        deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
        //imageButton
        addProImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addProImg);
        //add photo on start
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(User.getPhotoUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(addProImage);
        // request permission
        requestPermission();

        // open gallery
        openGallery();

        // delete mStorage data
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(User.getPhotoUrl() == PhotoDownloadUri){
                    mStorage.child("UserPhoto").child(photoUri.getLastPathSegment()).delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                //photo replaced with default photo
                                addProImage.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Photo deleted Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });

        // Add update user profile info
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String Name =UsernameEt.getText().toString().trim();
                String Photouri = PhotoDownloadUri.toString();
                // Calling method
                updateUserProfileInfo(Name,Photouri);
            }
        });

    }//onCreate end here

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    //method for open gallery
    private void openGallery(){
        //image Button getting gallery intent
        addProImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryPickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryPickIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryPickIntent,REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    //request permittion
    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            openGallery();
        }
    }

    //on Activity result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE || requestCode ==RESULT_OK){
            photoUri =  data.getData();
            // add photo to imageView
            addProImage.setImageURI(photoUri);

            //
            //upload photo in firebase database
            //
            mStorage.child("UserPhoto").child(photoUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(photoUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    PhotoDownloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            mStorage.child("UserPhoto").child(photoUri.getLastPathSegment()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
               //PhotoDownloadUri = uri;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //checking gallery permission
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            openGallery();
        }
    }

    //update user profile info name and photo
    public void updateUserProfileInfo(String name, String photoUri){
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(name)
                .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(photoUri))
                .build();

        User.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //setting user profile data to firebase database
                            mRef.child("Users").child(User.getUid()).child("username").setValue(User.getDisplayName());
                            mRef.child("Users").child(User.getUid()).child("photouri").setValue(User.getPhotoUrl());
                            mRef.child("Users").child(User.getUid()).child("uid").setValue(User.getUid());

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Profile Update Successful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // add photo to edit
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

Screenshot of my result:

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you checked the android logs?  I'd generally include any logs/trace in your question by default

Comment: there is no error sowed

Comment: try using ``Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true)`` to see the logs for any errors. And also try removing ``fit().centerCrop()`` if that works .

Comment: `04-14 02:40:13.135 24733-24822/com.example.rongbuzz.citicitichat D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+1281ms for error
04-14 02:40:13.342 24733-24822/com.example.rongbuzz.citicitichat D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+1488ms 
04-14 02:40:13.347 24733-24733/com.example.rongbuzz.citicitichat D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1]+1492ms `

Comment: `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(profileImg);
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true);`

Comment: What does getPhotoUrl() actually return?

Comment: not any error in return . it's return Uri , but it's not load in imageView . i try adding direct link of the image that worked but when i use User.getPhotoUri it's show nothing but a white space like in the screenshort

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String url = user.getPhotoUrl(); //"gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg"

// Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);


gsReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // handle success
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: but i need to get data from Firebase user because  it will be profile page and every Current user info has to be update with user authentication